# How to interrupt a thread from waiting to receive a udp packet?

Tags: java, multithreading, udp, packet

I have the following code:

```
    public class ServerConnectionListener implements Runnable {


    DatagramSocket receiveSocket;
    DatagramPacket receivePacket;
    /*
    Some Initilization here in the constructor 
    //
    //
    */


    @Override
    public void run() 
    {
    try {        
         System.out.println("Waiting..."); // so we know we're waiting
         receiveSocket.receive(receivePacket);
      } catch (IOException e) 
         {
         System.out.print("IO Exception: likely:");
         e.printStackTrace();
         System.exit(1);
         }

    //Some more stuff to be done here

    }
 }
```

I know that receiveSocket.receive() is a blocking call. Therefore, I want to use Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() in such a way that it allows me to interrupt this thread without having to wait for the packet to be received any more.

Comment: You could close the socket from another thread. That will cause `receive` to throw an exception.

Comment: Yes, That will sure work :) . But let's say that the other thread does not have the reference of socket. Is there anything I can do in that case?

Comment: Put a `close` method into `ServerConnectionListener`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot safely interrupt a thread that is blocked on a socket receive.

The simple way to accomplish this is to set a reasonable timeout value (`DatagramSocket.setSoTimeout(int milliseconds)`), i.e. 1 second, and check an interrupt flag on each `SocketTimeoutException`.

A better but more complex (from a coding standpoint) solution is to use the facilities of `java.nio.channels`.

Comment: Why couldn't you safely interrupt such thread? How about calling `close()` on the socket? What would make it unsafe?